# Google Map Marking

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have created a page. There I would like to use google maps. In the locater  section I want to parse long and lat value using variables. I have tried, but it's not working. Please can some one help me?

Code:

```
function initMap() {
var lats = "-33.8674769";
var lngs = "151.20697759999996";
var myLatLng = {"lat": lats, "lng": lngs};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatLng
  });
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

Comment: var lats = -33.8674769;
var lngs = 151.20697759999996;
just remove string , dats it

Comment: Look at the javascript console in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kxt0b09o/), there are two errors: `Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number` and `Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse your lat and long to a float datatype:

This should work:

```
function initMap() {
var lats = "-33.8674769";
var lngs = "151.20697759999996";
var myLatLng = {"lat": parseFloat(lats), "lng": parseFloat(lngs)};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatLng
  });
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
initMap();
```

Here is the fiddle prove: http://jsfiddle.net/dFjdy/347/